# Binarize pandas column based on list

Tags: python, pandas, binary

I have a list of values like

```
mylist = ["001k","002k"..."400k"]
```

and a pandas df like

```
id   code
1    500k
2    001k
...
100  400k
```

I would like to binarize the values of `code` based on `mylist`.
Hence, row 1 receives 0 everywhere because `"500k"` is not in `mylist`.
Alternatively, row 2 receives 1 at `"001k"` column and 0 elsewhere.
The final df would seems like

```
id   001k   002k   ...   400k
1     0      0            0
2     1      0            0
...
100   0      0            1
```

Comment: Do you want just to have the informations on one columns, or are you looking for [dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do batch comparisons using numpy, giving you booleans:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array(["001k", "002k", "400k"])
>>> y = np.array(["500k", "001k", "400k"])
>>> x[None, :] == y[:, None]
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

From there, it's simple to transform it to integers:

```
>>> (x[None, :] == y[:, None]).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

You can then do that easily by taking `df["code"].values` and `np.array(mylist)` which are numpy arrays e.g.

```
mylist = ["001k","002k","300k","400k"]
x = np.array(mylist)
df = pd.DataFrame({'code':['500k','600k','001k','002k','001k','400k']})
y = df["code"].values
ndf = pd.DataFrame((x[None, :] == y[:, None]).astype(int),columns=mylist)
```

Output:

```
  001k  002k  300k  400k
0     0     0     0     0
1     0     0     0     0
2     1     0     0     0
3     0     1     0     0
4     1     0     0     0
5     0     0     0     1
```

Comment: I think this is what Op meant +1

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edits, you're looking for [dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
pd.get_dummies(df["code"])
```

output

```
id   001k   002k   ...   400k
1     0      0            0
2     1      0            0
...
100   0      0            1
```

Comment: No `get_dummies` also consider data out of `mylist`

Comment: @Bharathshetty Thanks for the remark, i forgot about that after his edit. : )

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
df["code"] = df["code"].apply(lambda x: x in mylist)
```

Comment: This will return True of False, not 0 or 1, you could try lambda x: int(x in mylist) instead

Comment: It's pretty much the same. True and False are 0 and 1.

Comment: Sure in a sense, but that's not the format expect by him, he wanted 0 and 1. So i just suggest a transformation to your solution to fit better his need. : )